# Proving function's continuity

Tags: calculus

Prove $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $D$, if:

$g(x)=f(x,y)$ is continuous in the variable $x$, for every $y$.

$h(h)=f(x,y)$ satisfies Lipschitz continuity criteria. (There exists a constant $L>0$, so that $|h(y)−h(y′)|⩽L|y−y′|$ for random points $(x,y)∈D$ and $(x,y′)∈D$.)

I'm unfamiliar with Lipschitz continuity and I could use some help on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Fix a point $(x_0,y_0)$. To prove continuity at $(x_0,y_0)$, write $\vert f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)\vert\leq \vert f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)\vert +\vert f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)\vert$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Try taking a sequence $(x_n, y_n)\in D$ converging to $(x, y)\in D$ and prove that 
$$(1) \lvert f(x_n, y_n) - f(x, y)\rvert \to 0.$$
Your adversary is the fact that in (1) you have both $y_n$ and $y$, which might be different, so you cannot apply Lipschitz condition directly. Try solving it by means of the triangle inequality, with a typical $2\epsilon$ argument.